# Wsdl in SUDs with Python/Django Error

Tags: python, wsdl, suds

So I am doing a basic web service call using an url for the application within python. I am just testing the connection to see if the web service responds back. My code is as follows:

```
from suds.client import Client

client = Client("File:///C:/Users/zsssss/Documents/TrannsTubalService.wsdl")

print client
```

However, I keep on getting an error as follows:

```
pydev debugger: starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\zsssss\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013012902\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1397, in <module>
debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
File "C:\Users\zsssss\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.0.2013012902\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1090, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
File "C:\Users\zsssss\My Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\sudsclient\src\transtube.py", line 7, in <module>
client = Client("File:///C:/Users/zn483d/Documents/TrannsTubalService.wsdl")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 112, in __init__
self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 152, in open
d = self.fn(url, self.options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\wsdl.py", line 159, in __init__
self.build_schema()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\wsdl.py", line 220, in build_schema
self.schema = container.load(self.options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\xsd\schema.py", line 93, in load
child.open_imports(options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\xsd\schema.py", line 305, in open_imports
imported = imp.open(options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\xsd\sxbasic.py", line 542, in open
result = self.download(options)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\xsd\sxbasic.py", line 560, in download
d = reader.open(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 79, in open
d = self.download(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 95, in download
fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\https.py", line 60, in open
return  HttpTransport.open(self, request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 62, in open
return self.u2open(u2request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 118, in u2open
return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
'_open', req)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 1310, in file_open
return self.open_local_file(req)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 1350, in open_local_file
raise URLError(msg)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: u'C:\\Users\\zsssss\\Documents\\TrannsTubalResponse.xsd'>
```

Comment: Have you tried with just the filename like this: `'C:/Users/zsssss/Documents/TrannsTubalService.wsdl'`? Since it's a local file why use the `File:///` is what I'm thinking.

Comment: You might also give this a shot: `'File:///C|/Users/zsssss/Documents/TrannsTubalService.wsdl'` Note the "pipe" instead of the colon.

Comment: When I just do     'C:/Users/zsssss/Documents/TrannsTubalService.wsdl' I get this error:     raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type) urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>

Comment: When I add the "pipe", I get the same error as the original statement.

Comment: No references to django in this question, I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of old question but had the same problem. To do this I used pathlib:

```
import pathlib
filepath = '/var/www/yourwsdlfile.extension'
fileuri = pathlib.Path(filepath).as_uri()
client = Client(url=fileuri)
```

Worked for me using suds-jurko 0.6 on Ubuntu. I noticed my fileuri ended up as 
'file:///var/www/secureitemdelivery.asmx'